# Realizar petición Ajax a través de un Select

Tags: javascript, laravel

Tengo una vista index blade donde muestro una tabla con órdenes médicas que traigo desde el controller sin problemas.

```
        <table class="table table-hover table-sm table-responsive">
        <thead>
          <th>Orden</th>
          <th>Impresión</th>
          <th>Socio</th>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Profesional</th>
          <th>Monto</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          @foreach($orders as $order)
            <tr>
              <td>{{ $order->id }}</td>
              <td>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($order->fechaImpresion)->format('d/m/Y') }}</td>
              <td>{{ $order->user->group->nroSocio }}</td>
              <td>{{ $order->user->name }}</td>
              <td>{{ $order->doctor->apeynom }}</td>
              <td>{{ $order->monto }}</td>
            </tr>
          @endforeach
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Ahora bien, he agregado un select que muestra los profesionales, los médicos, y seleccionando uno quiero filtrar las órdenes correspondientes a ese médico, pero como verán para completar los datos utilizo las relaciones entre models de eloquent (por ejemplo {{ $order->user->group->nroSocio }}), entonces la duda está en como generar la colección en el controller, recibirla con una promesa manteniendo esas relaciones de eloquent en la colección, y actualizar los datos con javascript.

La ruta:

```
Route::get('orders/search/{id}', 'OrderController@getOrdenes')
                ->middleware(['auth','can:orders.show'])
                ->name('orders.search');
```

En el model Doctor:

```
   public function orders(){return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Order','doctor_id');}
```

En el model Order

```
 public function doctor()
{
return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Doctor');
}

  public function user()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User','pacient_id');
  }
```

En el model User:

```
public function orders()
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Order','pacient_id');
}
```

Entonces tengo el select:

```
                <select class="custom-select" name="doctor" id="doctor" onchange="cargarOrdenes()">
                  <option selected>Seleccione profesional</option>
                  @foreach($doctors as $doctor)
                    <option value="{{ $doctor->id }}">
                      {{ $doctor->apeynom }}
                    </option>
                  @endforeach
                </select>
```

Entonces aquí me faltan el método del controller donde genero la colección, y la función javascript que recibe y actualiza la vista.

Comment: Agrega el código de tu controlador donde recibes el valor del Select

Comment: Agregado, y la ruta

Comment: Pues al menos lo que se, es que si vamos a ocupar JS por que no se me ocurre de que otro modo leer el evento change del select que será disparado cuando el usuario seleccione un nuevo elemento de la lista, por otro lado **eso no tiene por que afectar en ningún sentido el uso de las relaciones de Eloquent, pues son cosas distintas**, pudieramos no requerir de JS pero si colocamos el select dentro de un form y la acción de envío la delegamos a un submit

Comment: Exacto, parece que si o si es con JS, antes lo había armado con un form, dentro el select y un button para ejecutar el submit, pero no encontraba forma de asignarle el id del doctor seleccionado al form, por eso intentaba con los <a>... nunca trabajé con las relaciones de Eloquent dentro de JS, pero lo voy a investigar, gracias.

Comment: Adelante, ya si con algo de eso no logras avanzar entonces ahi sugiero edites la pregunta y añadas esos detalles

Comment: Edité con la solución que encontré.

Comment: como ya sabes la solución va en la solución va en la zona de respuestas y no en la pregunta, por favor quitala de tu publicación y muevela a la zona que corresponde

Comment: Además ya vez te pude responder con la solución, pues de todos modos si terminaste usando el evento `change` en JS, en fin realiza lo que te pido arriba por favor

Answer (score 1):

Un saludo, primeramente te recomiendo que coloques un / al comienzo de tu ruta

```
Route::get('/orders/search/{id}', 'OrderController@getOrdenes')
                ->middleware(['auth','can:orders.show'])
                ->name('orders.search');
```

Usualmente cuando se declara una ruta que va a recibir una Inyección de Dependencias se debe declarar un where. de estaforma.

```
Route::get('/orders/search/{id}', 'OrderController@getOrdenes')
                    ->where('id', '[0-9]+') 
                    ->middleware(['auth','can:orders.show'])
                    ->name('orders.search');
```

Y en el controlador en la dependendencia debe ir la clase junto con la variable id que declaraste en la ruta.:

```
public function getOrdenes(Ordenes $id)
```

Y en el blade hazlo de esta manera, una forma rápida de resolver el disparo de la ruta es usar un dropdown no un select, para este ejemplo he colocado un dropdown con clases de bootstrap 4:

```html
<div class="dropdown mb-4">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="width: 150px">
                {{ $doctor->apeynom }}
   </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu animated--fade-in" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    @foreach ($doctors as $doctor) 
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/clicks_report/{{$doctor->doctor->id}}">{{ $doctor->apeynom}}</a>
    @endforeach
  </div>
```

Comment: Realmente no es un select, debe ser un dropdown menu, cada vez que elija una opcion del dropdown dispara la ruta cambiando la información filtrada por id, ya corrijo lo de select.

Comment: El no está enviando un formulario por lo que entiendo esta llamando una ruta con un id para filtrar la información por doctor al parecer, por lo que llenará la tabla con la información solicitada en la ruta, cada link vuelve a disparar el controlador solo que con la información del id que el envie.

Comment: Gracias! edité con la solución que encontré.

Answer (score 0):

La función cargarOrdenes() de javascript, lo que debe hacer es tomar el id del doctor seleccionado, ejecutar la llamada para traer los datos filtrados, borrar los registros que tenga actualmente la vista y cargar una fila en la tabla por cada registro nuevo:

```
function cargarOrdenes(){var id = document.getElementById('doctor').value;


 axios.post('/getOrdenes/'+id)
    .then((resp)=>{
      var tabla = document.getElementById('tablaordenes');
      var cont = tabla.rows.length;
      for (i = 0; i < (cont); i++) {
          document.getElementById("borrar").remove();
      }
      for (i = 0; i < Object.keys(resp.data).length; i++) {
        tabla.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<tr id="borrar"><td>' + resp.data[i].id + '</td><td>' + resp.data[i].fechaImpresion + '</td><td>' + resp.data[i].numeroSocio + '</td><td>' + resp.data[i].user.name + '</td><td>' + resp.data[i].nombreDoctor + '</td><td>' + resp.data[i].monto + '</td></tr>');
      }
    })
    .catch(function (error) {console.log(error);})
};
```

La función del controlador a la que apunta la ruta y obtiene los datos filtrados, aquí está lo que he aprendido, para que el arreglo enviado contenga las relaciones eloquent (una es de la órden con el paciente o user, y la otra con el doctor que hizo la atención) debo hacer el foreach de abajo:

```
public function getOrdenes($id)
{
  $orders = Order::where('doctor_id', '=', $id)->get();
  foreach($orders as $order){
      $order->numeroSocio = $order->user->group->nroSocio;
      $order->nombreDoctor = $order->doctor->apeynom;
  }
  return $orders;
}
```

Al hacer este foreach, en la colección del órdenes que envío se activan automáticamente las relaciones eloquent de los models user y doctor. Y se utilizan como hice en la función de javascript cargarOrdenes().

Espero que le sirva a alguien más, hasta ahora no sabía que la relaciones de eloquent las podía llevar a javascript.

Comment: No olvides marcar como aceptada aquella respuesta que te resolvió el problema